# simple animation is skipping on older devices

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-animation, onclicklistener, android-transitions

I have a RecyclerView with multiple TextViews and a Button. The button triggers an animation like the gif below:

[image]

I am doing this by creating a `RecyclerView.Adapter` and creating an `OnClickListener` like so:

```
public class recyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<recyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<MyObject> objects;
    // constructor and other stuff ...

    public void setDefaultRequestBtnClickListener(View.OnClickListener defaultRequestBtnClickListener) {
        this.defaultRequestBtnClickListener = defaultRequestBtnClickListener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        MyObject object = objects.get(position);

        if (object.getRequestBtnClickListener() != null) {
            holder.Btn.setOnClickListener(object.getRequestBtnClickListener());
        }else {
            holder.Btn.setOnClickListener(defaultRequestBtnClickListener);
        }
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        TextView value;
        TextView currentVal;
        TextView Btn;
        ConstraintLayout parent;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            value = itemView.findViewById(R.id.totalPrice);
            currentVal = itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkBtn);
            Btn = itemView.findViewById(R.id.animateBtn);
            parent = itemView.findViewById(R.id.parent);
        }

        public void bind(final OnMyClickListener listener) {
            parent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override public void onClick(View v) {
                    listener.onMyClick(v, getLayoutPosition());
                }
            });
        }

    }

     public interface OnMyClickListener{
        void onMyClick(View view, int position);

    }
}
```

this creates and binds a `viewholder` in a `recyclerview` to the `TextViews` and buttons. At the moment a user has to click the element to activate the `Btn` and animation. The below is the `Fragment` that is initiating the adapter:

```
 @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_object_layout, container, false);

        final RecyclerView recyclerView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);
        final ArrayList<MyObject> objects = MyObject.getTestingList();
        final recyclerViewAdapter adapter =  new recyclerViewAdapter(objects, getContext());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

        adapter.setDefaultRequestBtnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                recyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder holder = (recyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder) recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(Position);

                if (holder != null) {
                    if (holder.value.getAlpha() == 0.0f) {
                        holder.value.animate().alpha(1.0f).setDuration(500);
                        holder.value.animate().translationY(-38).setDuration(1000);
                        holder.checkValue.animate().translationY(38).setDuration(1000);
                    } else {
                        holder.value.animate().alpha(0.0f).setDuration(500);
                        holder.value.animate().translationY(0).setDuration(500);
                        holder.checkValue.animate().translationY(0).setDuration(500);
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        adapter.setOnMyClickListener(new recyclerViewAdapter.OnMyClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMyClick(View view, int pos) {
                Position = pos;
                holder = (recyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder) recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(Position);

            }
        });


        return rootView;
    }
}
```

This is all working great on an emulator, but on an older device the animation is skipping and the views go directly to their final position. Why is that? I checked the processing time and it is below the 16ms threshold.

How can I improve this?

(Posting the whole code is difficult here. ask for code and I will update the question)

Comment: can u try it on low powerful new devices which runs on oreo

usually android skips animation to save cpu cycle when there is high demand

Comment: @Eldhopj by "low powerful" you mean low power mode?

Comment: budget devices, ie, which uses low end cpu

Comment: @Eldhopj I tried it on low end 2015 samsung device. I wish I had a new low end phone but I do not at the moment. Even if so, is there anything I can do to solve the issue?